# if statement doesn't work in Jade when comparing Mongoose Object Ids

Tags: templates, express, mongoose, pug

So I have a story object and I am trying to compare it to an array of stories to see if the story object is in the array. However it's not working and I can't figure out why.

```
//news.jade

each post in favPosts
    div=post._id
    div=object._id
    if (post._id === object._id)
        span same
    else
        span no

// the output (those are ObjectID from mongoose)

55e3e6dcd22670d8032a4ddf
55ef8999a89ed2fc72d8159f
no

55e3e6bbd22670d8032a4dde
55ef8999a89ed2fc72d8159f
no

55ef8999a89ed2fc72d8159f
55ef8999a89ed2fc72d8159f
no <=== this should be same

55ef8028283872046809c0f2
55ef8999a89ed2fc72d8159f
no
```

Comment: Can you try type casting both to mongo db object ids?

Comment: You probably need to use `==` rather than `===`, though it seems like they should be the same type and thus it shouldn't be needed. Also you might want to consider a more efficent approach for comparison checking depending on how your using it. (IE: Finding an article with a specific id. If your going to do something with all the articles then it probably won't matter though, and you can ignore this last bit.)

Comment: Can you try `div= typeof post._id` `div= typeof object._id` to see what are their types ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ObjecId` instances are objects and so are compared like objects, not primitives.
You should use either

```
post._id.equals(object._id)
```

or

```
post._id.toString() === object._id.toString()
```